# In ubuntu my camera isnt working ,no device found ,both on cheese and google meet

Tags: apt, 22.04, webcam, ffmpeg

I use Ubuntu on pen-drive and the OS was working well till last night[ 8 Nov] but today after running my code related computer vision, I did have a system software update prior I was about to use google meet, the whole camera thing stopped working I have tried all method of terminal commands over internet  on my laptop(Mac book Air 2017) yet it failed, As i am running it over a pen drive i borrowed a laptop [Lenovo think-pad 2020] found camera is working over that system, my problem now is that i want it to work on my laptop till I complete my computer vision project please help me out. Adding on I don't want to use 3rd party gits and packages over my system as a security concern.

I did try a fresh installation of the Ubuntu on my pen drive without updating the OS yet i got same result

I did try formatting my mac book and reinstalling Macos yet it didnt work

I tried "sudo killall VDCAssistant on mac terminal it did not work

I have tried following cmds , [Non of them worked, I did try 3rd party also but it didn't work , i did try apple firmware related git repo it didn't work too!]

I also check the camera hardware it works fine on macOS and bootcamp windows

### I did get this

/dev/video*  no such dir found

sudo modprobe -r uvcvideo && sudo modprobe uvcvideo

```
sudo apt-get install cheese build-essential Linux-headers-`name -r`

ls -l /dev/video0

    8  sudo chown root:video /dev/video*

    9  sudo chmod 666 /dev/video*

   10  uname -a

   11  lsusb

   12  gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0

   13  sudo apt install gphoto2

   14  sudo apt install ffmpeg

   15  sudo apt install gphoto2

   16  sudo apt install ffmpeg
   17  gphoto2 --stdout --capture-movie | ffmpeg -i - -vcodec rawvideo -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video0

   18  lsusb

   19  sudo chown root:video /dev/video*

   20  sudo chmod 666 /dev/video*

   21  pip3 install pillow

   22  sudo apt-get remove --purge "LibreOffice*"

   23  sudo apt-get clean

   24  sudo apt-get autoremove

   25  lsusb

   26  vcgencmd get_camera

   27  sudo apt-get install fswebcam
```